# Is there a connection between Space-Time Vortex and Gravitational Waves?

Tags: spacetime, gravitational-waves, vortex

Is there a connection between [Space-Time Vortex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkAPv5s92z0&) and gravitational waves?

[Space-Time Vortex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkAPv5s92z0&)

Comment: It's all described by the same equations... if that helps.

Comment: It is completely unclear what this question is referring to by "Space-Time Vortex" without watching a YouTube video. To protect against link rot and to make the question more accessible, please include all relevant information into the question itself, instead of relying on external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space time vortex is caused by frame dragging when a massive object spins.  For example, [the Gravity Probe B experiment](http://www.pcworld.com/article/227240/experiment_confirms_space_time_vortext_around_earth_makes_our_heads_hurt.html) found that the Earth drags space time curvature with it as it spins; a vortex of space time curvature forms around the Earth.  The axis of the space time vortex drifts as the earth spins, and this drift is what Gravity Probe B was able to measure.

A [gravitational wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) is a manifestation of the same space time curvature that can be twisted into a vortex.  But a gravitational wave does not remain localized around a massive object.  It is a ripple in the curvature of space time that propagates outward from its source.

While Gravity Probe B confirmed existence of a space time vortex, the [recent announcement of confirmation of existence of gravitational waves](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2016/feb/11/gravitational-waves-discovery-hailed-as-breakthrough-of-the-century) confirmed that disturbances in space time curvature, caused by the acceleration of massive objects, propagate through space time and carry information.

Comment: so do you say that gravitational waves are amplified vortexes ?

Comment: also, does the drag cause tension in the fabric of space time?

Comment: also, does the spinning speed of earth effect the vortex in any shape or form?

Comment: also, will space vortex allow us to unravel things about the universes?

Comment: also, why space time behave like water by having waves and vortexes?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a connection between a Space-Time Vortex and gravitational waves?

Yes. Take a look at [this NASA article](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2011/04may_epic/) about Gravity Probe B and gravitomagnetism: *"Einstein was right again. There is a space-time vortex around Earth, and its shape precisely matches the predictions of Einstein's theory of gravity."*

[image]
<sup>Public domain image courtesy of NASA</sup>

One of the people who comments in this article is Clifford M Will, the author of [The Confrontation between General Relativity and Experiment](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377). He also commented on the [LIGO announcement](http://www.nature.com/news/gravitational-waves-6-cosmic-questions-they-can-tackle-1.19337), and the fact that he's chipping in indicates that these phenomena are connected. They're both associated with predictions coming out of general relativity.

Note however that a gravitomagnetic field is not the same thing as a gravitational wave, just as a magnetic field is not the same thing as an electromagnetic wave. I can probably best explain the distinction using the old [rubber-sheet analogy](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EUM_VY2-Juiq8wfv_oCgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=rubber+sheet+analogy). A gravitational field is a dimple in the rubber sheet, like what you'd get if you put a bowling ball on it. A gravitational wave is a ripple in the rubber sheet, like what you'd get if you grabbed hold of the edge of it and shook it. Or chucked a bowling ball onto it - the sheet would bounce around for a while. A gravitomagnetic field is like what you'd get if you grabbed the rubber sheet and twisted it round. Or made the bowling ball spin, such that it dragged the rubber sheet around a little.

A better analogy would use a gin-clear ghostly elastic three-dimensional bulk to represent space, but that's harder to imagine. So we'll save that one for another day.